# Como é feita a contagem dos votos na eleição?

Tags: debate, eleição

O post sobre a eleição fala que os votos serão contados de acordo com o método VUT:

> Cada pessoa tem direito a 3 votos: sua 1ª, 2ª e 3ª escolhas para moderador. Os votos são contabilizados usando o Método VUT.

Que método é esse? Suspeito que ele seja bem diferente do jeito normal de se contar votos em uma eleição, e mesmo quem já participou de eleições em algum outro site do Stack Exchange pode não saber como ele funciona exatamente. O [artigo da Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voto_%C3%BAnico_transfer%C3%ADvel) não é muito claro.

Como funciona esse método?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

O Método VUT é um processo iterativo, que se aproxima de uma representação justa da vontade do público assintoticamente.

O seu voto tem peso `1,00`, e é dado aos seus candidatos na ordem em que você escolher. Cada candidato só fica com a quantidade de votos que é necessária para conseguir a eleição, dividido igualmente entre todos que votaram nela. O resto decimal do seu voto é então repassado ao seu próximo candidato. Caso ele já esteja fora da corrida, seu voto é repassado à sua próxima escolha.

Não ficou muito claro, né? Melhor com um exemplo. Imagine a seguinte situação...

- 24 eleitores
- 6 candidatos
- 3 vagas

Nesse caso, são necessários ao menos **7** votos para garantir uma vaga¹. Já que não é possível que outras 3 pessoas recebam *mais* que 7 votos. Esse número de votos é dado pela fórmula de Droop:

```
(votos / (vagas + 1)) + 1
```

Durante a votação, cada eleitor determina sua primeira, segunda e terceira escolhas de candidatos.

No início da votação, todos os votos são atribuídos aos candidatos marcados como **1ª Escolha**. Então você pergunta: "Algum candidato atingiu o número de votos necessário para ser eleito?"

- **Sim**
  Se algum candidato recebeu pelo menos 7 votos, ele é considerado eleito, e o seu "excesso" de votos (o número de votos acima do necessário para ser eleito) é distribuido para as **2ª Escolhas** daqueles votos.

  Por exemplo, se cada voto tem peso `1,00` e o *Candidato A* recebeu 10 votos, cada voto para A a ter peso 0,7 e o 0,3 restante vai para a **2ª Escolha** daquele eleitor. Assim, o *Candidato A* continua tendo 7 votos, o que garante sua eleição, e as **2ª Escolhas** de cada um de seus eleitores também recebe uma parcela de votos
- **Não**
  Se nenhum candidato atingiu o requisito para ser eleito, o candidato com menos votos é removido da corrida. Seus votos são distribuidos para as **2ª Escolhas** de cada um dos seus eleitores.

Depois disso é calculado um novo requisito de votos para se conseguir a eleição, já que alguns votos foram dados para candidatos que já foram eliminados e são desconsiderados, e é feita a mesma pergunta. Esse processo é repetido até que se tenham apenas 3 candidatos restantes, todos com o número de votos igual ao mínimo necessário para eleição.

Se todos os candidatos de um eleitor forem eliminados, esses votos não tem mais valor na eleição.

Os votos em excesso de um candidato são redistribuidos *antes* de se eliminar qualquer outro candidato. Por isso escolher um candidato popular não é "desperdiçar o voto" nesse tipo de eleição.

---

**¹** Esse número é recalculado durante a contagem de votos, a cada passo do processo. O [artigo em Inglês na Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meek%27s_method#Meek.27s_method) explica melhor esse processo.

Comment: E eu estava achando que meu problema era com o Inglês.. =/

Comment: Ah já entendi, nada que uma segunda leitura não resolva. ;)

Comment: TL;DR _"Os votos nas primárias não são contabilizados para a contagem que decide os vencedores da eleição. Os votos na fase final são contabilizados de uma forma que não haja desperdício e evite o voto tático na escolha da ordem dos candidatos."_ Me corrija se eu estiver errado. Acho que o mais me confundiu foi que no início da explicação não falava a relação entre os votos das primárias com os votos da eleição, e eu não sabia a qual das etapas se referia o peso de `1,00`. Um pouco também por não fazer ideia do que significa "assintoticamente".

Comment: Eu ainda não entendi bem os votos na primária, já que pelo descrito, não considera os votos negativos, que elevam o peso dos demais votos sempre que alguém recebe mais um.

Comment: @Delfino Os votos nas primárias não seguem esse padrão. Apenas na fase final. As primárias são com votos simples contra e a favor