# Quantos pontos de reputação preciso para me candidatar a moderador?

Tags: debate, moderação

Existe uma votação para eleger moderadores? Existe um número mínimo de pontuação para que um usuário possa se candidatar ao cargo de moderador?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sim existe uma [eleição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election) para definir quem serão os moderadores.

No início(beta) da comunidade/site os moderadores são indicados pela SE, após o site se estabelecer acontecem as eleições que são dividas em três etapas:

1) definição das candidaturas, 2) primárias, 3) votação definitiva.

Qualquer usuário com mais de 300 pontos pode se canditatar a moderador.

Relacionado:

[O que é a eleição? Como ela funciona?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3882/91)

[Como é feita a contagem dos votos na eleição?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3953/91)

[Diferença de Moderador ♦ para Usuário Confiável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3963/91)

[Aproveite a Copa com moderação!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1452/91)

Answer (score 6):

Existem muitas tarefas aqui que você pode fazer sem ser moderador, inclusive você pode obter ferramentas pra moderação do conteúdo do site, por exemplo:

- A partir dos 2.000 pode editar perguntas e respostas, as edições de qualquer pergunta ou resposta são aplicadas imediatamente
- 2.500 criar sinônimos da tag, pode decidir quais tags têm o mesmo significado que outras
- 3.000 votar para suspender ou reabrir, pode ajudar a decidir se as publicações estão descontextualizadas ou duplicadas
- 5.000 aprovar edições do wiki de tag, pode aprovar edições nos wikis de tag feitos por usuários regulares
- 10.000 acesso às ferramentas do moderador, lidar com sinalizações, acessar relatórios, excluir perguntas
- 15.000 proteger perguntas, pode marcar perguntas como protegidas
- 20.000 usuário confiável, pode expansão dos privilégios de edição, exclusões e cancelamento de exclusões

**Veja esta página pra mais detalhes:** [Central de ajuda > Privilégios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Então note que muitas ações aqui não são realizadas pelos moderadores, mas sim pelos **usuários estabelecidos**.

Tendo entendido isto, **faça esta pergunta pra si mesmo**:

## O que um moderador pode fazer que um usuário com privilégios expandidos não pode?

- Se você souber a diferença, então você provavelmente tem um motivo muito forte pra querer se candidatar.
- Se você não sabe a diferença, então provavelmente você se tornar um usuário com mais de 2.000 pontos seria o melhor caminho.

Então pense assim, não é preciso ser moderador pra colaborar com a comunidade, basta mostrar um certa eficiência.

Posso dizer que é mais vantajoso ser um usuário com privilégios expandidos, pois este não tem uma "obrigação" de comparecer. Muitos se candidataram, mas realmente eles não entendiam o motivo ou diferença dos moderadores e até mesmo alguns acham que usuário com mais privilégios são moderadores.

Sei que deve ter ficado curioso pra saber qual a diferença e este link pode lhe ajudar:

- [Diferença de Moderador ♦ para Usuário Confiável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3963/3635)

O sinal de `♦` é o que define se o usuário é moderador.

Comment: isto ---> "faça esta pergunta para si mesmo" <--- otsi

Comment: @brasofilo faltaram alguns :P

Comment: @JorgeB. Sabe o que é COT? O mesmo que TOC (Transtorno Obsessivo Compulsivo), só que com as letrinhas na ordem correta :D

Comment: @brasofilo estou meio lento hoje, voce esta corrigindo o meu portugues ou esta dando enfase ao meu comentario - as vezes sou um pouco lento pra entender :)

Comment: seu português parece perfeito, talvez seus dedos é que esqueçam uma tecla de vez em quando ;) ... minha 1a edição não foi completa, o Jorge avançou com uma 2a mas ainda ficou faltando, daí minha 3a.... a ênfase no "faça esta pergunta" não está relacionada com as edições...

Comment: @brasofilo sobre os erros de digitacao, eu sei que parece estranho, mas meu notebook queimou (literalmente saiu fumaça), estou no momento usando um notebook com teclado britânico (o que dificulta muito a minha digitação). Eu tento usar o corretor do navegador, mas ele não e perfeito. :) Estou esperando meu novo notebook chegar, mas ainda nao foi despachado. Prometo que vou corrigir tudo.

Comment: @brasofilo sobre o "faça esta pergunta para si mesmo" eu so fiquei em duvida devido a eu ter escrito "faça essa pergunta pra si mesmo", eu usei "essa" e "pra" ao inves de "esta" e "para", pensei que fosse algum erro de escrita rs. Mas da maneira que escreveu parece melhor, vou editar.